# Same WAR works differently @ same machine under different JDK & Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Our WAR working perfectly in Redhat 6.4 with Jre1.8.0_92 & Tomcat8.0.32 at staging environment.

When we moved our same Staging WAR to Production Server with same configuration (Redhat 6.4 with Jre 1.8.0_92 & Tomcat8.0.32). We got the following errors in the catalina console.

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 38 more

Nov 01, 2017 2:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class gov.nic.gep.general.servlet.ServletContextManagerServices
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 38 more

Nov 01, 2017 2:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 01, 2017 2:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/nicgep] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 01, 2017 2:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class gov.nic.gep.general.servlet.ServletContextManagerServices
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 38 more
```

**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
**

But, the same WAR working perfectly in other production servers with same configuration and their OS is Redhat6.7.

If, I tried to resolve the exception by importing hibernate3.3.jar at classpath. Some other Class Not Exception thrown which are related to Spring-transaction and these dependencies exceptions were coming endlessly. But the same WAR working without any exception in the jdk7&tomcat7 configuration at the same machine.

Our Application developed with tapestry4.1, hibernate3, spring4, axis2 and postgres as DB.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the compatibility of the JRE with different operating systems, as your title suggests. It has most likely to do with using different, incompatible versions of libraries on the different systems. Check that you use the exact same libraries on both systems.

Comment: @Jesper, Is it with Linux libraries or jar libraries ? Which is the same system with same WAR throws exception like these in jdk8. but, it works fine @ jdk7 environment. How Could it behaves differently in the same machine? Please check my latest update.

Comment: JAR libraries. Specifically, it looks like you are running this with a different version of Hibernate than what you compiled and tested it with, that does not have the class that it is complaining about.

Comment: Which is the same system with same WAR throws exception like these in jdk8. but, it works fine @ jdk7 environment. How Could it behaves differently in the same machine?

Comment: could hibernate be added as a 'global' dependency to one of your app servers but not the other? Check the tomcat7 lib folder for the hibernate deps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/454352/where-is-the-tomcat-7-home-lib-directory

Comment: Checked. No libs available other than tomcat bundled. We bundled all the application dependencies only @ WAR lib.